# itextsharp open pdf with another browser windows

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

basically below is the code for me to read pdf file, the output for this code below is ask client to download the pdf file and open it from client side, this is not what i want,what i want it open the pdf at another browswer windows or open in inside

tag under same browser windows, but how can i make it?

```
    var fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(@"~/AIA2.pdf"));
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                  String.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"",
                                 "AIA2.pdf"));
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fi.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.WriteFile(fi.FullName);
    Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not upto the server to decide how content is handled - content disposition could be set to attachment or inline but its to the handling application to process these and i do not think any browser does that.

I can suggest a two step solution for this:

1. Use inline; instead of attachment
2. On the client side (if you have control on that ofcourse), use something like

That should do the trick!

Comment: @Digvijay is correct, this is a client-side preference. If the client installs Adobe Acrobat and is using IE or Firefox then by default it will display inline although some people (like me) turn this off immediately. If the client is using a recent version of Chrome then it will also display inline using Google's PDF renderer. I believe the same holds true with Safari. I don't think that Opera has a native renderer but I'm not 100% sure. All that you can do from the server-side is say "I'm got some bytes, treat them as a PDF" and optionally provide a hint of "inline" or "attachment".